# Chemnum sublabels in section-titles not working properly

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chemnum

### Problem

I'm encountering the problem, that sublabeling

```
\cmpd+{cmpd:main.sub}
```

does not work properly in section-titles, since the sublables are missing in section-titles and ToC. Its also not working with

```
\cmpd+{main.sub}
```

where I thought, that maybe the colon is making problems.

Is this a known issue. And is there a simple way to fix this?

---

### M(N)WE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%
\section{Compounds \cmpd+{cmpd:1.a} and \cmpd+{cmpd:1.b}}
    Unfortunately, there is neither a differentiation between \cmpd{cmpd:1.a} and \cmpd{cmpd:1.b} in the section-title, nor in the ToC.
%
\end{document}
```

---

### LaTeX-Params

- Editor: **TeXstudio** (V: 2.7.0) (for the sake of completeness)
- Distribution: **MiKTeX** (V: 2.9.5105)
- Compiler: **LuaLaTeX**

Comment: Interesting. This is clearly a bug... I'll investigate and send an update to CTAN as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply! Looking forward to the update!
Anyways - chemnum is an extremely usefull, and nicely working package - Thanks for that as well :)

Comment: This issue is fixed in v1.0a (2014/05/30). The new version will be available on CTAN in a few days and in due time also in MiKTeX. This means that this question should probably be closed as »off-topic« (in this case »off-topic« means »is solved by updating the software«)

Comment: Alright! How can I close the question, and do I have to "accept" an answer?
Thanks again for your time an efforts!

Comment: It's now on CTAN: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.ctan.announce/11027

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is solved with an update

Comment: @cgnieder: With the updated package I get an error (_Missing number, treated as zero ...stuff (\cmpd+{proYl.{ChKn02,ChKn07,ChKn09}})}_) in the `.tex` file (or in the `.toc` file when having ToC), whenever I use

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\begin{document}
  \subsection{Preparation of stuff (\cmpd+{proYl.{ChKn02,ChKn07,ChKn09}})}
  Compounds \cmpd{proYl.{ChKn02,ChKn07,ChKn09}} have been...
\end{document}`

and compile it _twice_ (first run works perfectly fine). LaTeX params see orig Question

Shall I add this to the question, or move on to a new one?
(Sry for the untidyness)

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues/3

Comment: The issue is now fixed on https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum (v1.0b) If you happen to find any more of these bugs the easiest way for me will be if you report issues there or send me an email (the address is in the manual).